# Symfony 3.1 Post to Web Api

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to make a web API with Symfony but the POST method is not working. My code does not give any error.

Entity/Status:

```
<?php

namespace RestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 *
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="status")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Status
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nome", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $nome;
}
?>
```

POST Function (Controller/StatusController):

```
public function postStatusAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new Status();
    $form = $this->createForm(StatusType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $user;
    }
    //var_dump($form->getErrors());
    throw new HttpException(400, "Invalid data");

}
```

Form/StatusType:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * Date: 10/08/16
 * Time: 10:39
 */

namespace RestBundle\Form;


use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class StatusType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('nome', TextType::class);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'RestBundle\Entity\Status',
            'csrf_protection'   => false,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A controller MUST return a Response :

```
public function postStatusAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new Status();
    $form = $this->createForm(StatusType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response($user->getUsername());
    }
    //var_dump($form->getErrors());
    throw new HttpException(400, "Invalid data");

}
```